# Products' quantity calculation based on transactions stored in two different tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

```
ITEMS
+----+--------------------------+----------+
| id | nome                     | quantity |
+----+--------------------------+----------+
|  1 | Pantaloni beige          |       10 |
|  2 | Camicia cotone e seta    |        1 |
|  3 | Camicia da notte         |        5 |
|  4 | Completo notte           |        3 |
+----+--------------------------+----------+

TRANSACTIONS
+----+---------------------+----------+-------------+
| id | data                | quantity | id_articolo | 
+----+---------------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | 2016-07-19 15:28:09 |        3 |           1 |  
|  2 | 2016-07-19 15:29:50 |        1 |           1 |
|  3 | 2016-07-19 15:59:34 |        1 |           2 |
|  4 | 2016-07-19 16:00:59 |        1 |           3 |
|  5 | 2016-07-19 16:01:10 |        1 |         188 |
|  6 | 2016-07-19 16:11:15 |        1 |         193 |
|  7 | 2016-07-19 16:11:24 |        1 |         194 |
|  8 | 2016-07-19 16:11:55 |        1 |         195 |
|  9 | 2016-07-19 16:51:14 |        1 |         204 |
+----+---------------------+----------+-------------+

RETURNED_ITEMS
+----+---------+-------------+----------+
| id | id_reso | id_articolo | quantity |
+----+---------+-------------+----------+
|  1 |      54 |           1 |        6 |
|  2 |      54 |           3 |        1 |
|  3 |      54 |         392 |        1 |
|  4 |      54 |         398 |        1 |
+----+---------+-------------+----------+
```

joined on "transactions.id_articolo" = "returned_items.id_articolo" = "items.id"

I want to retrieve a complete list containing only available products in which

(items.quantity) - (transactions.quantity) - (returned_items.quantity) > 0

eg. In the data above

- item 1 = 0 [excluded]
- item 2 = 0 [excluded]
- item 3 = 3 [included in the list]
- item 4 = 3 [included]

Any idea?
Thanks a lot!
V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you will need to use inline views to aggregate `quantity` from the `transactions` table and the `returned items` tables

```
SELECT i.id
     , i.quantity
     , IFNULL(t.quantity,0) AS t_quantity
     , IFNULL(r.quantity,0) AS r_quantity
     , i.quantity - IFNULL(t.quantity,0) + IFNULL(r.quantity,0) AS calc_qty
  FROM items i
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT tt.id_articolo
              , SUM(tt.quantity) AS quantity 
          FROM transactions tt
         GROUP BY tt.id_articolo
       ) t
    ON t.id_articolo = i.id
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT rr.id_articolo
              , SUM(rr.quantity) AS quantity 
          FROM returned_items rr
         GROUP BY rr.id_articolo
       ) r
    ON r.id_articolo = i.id
HAVING calc_qty > 0 
 ORDER BY i.id
```

---

For testing, omit the `HAVING` clause.

Note that the expression for `calc_qty` in the query above includes an addition operation. Go ahead and combine the quantity values with whatever arithmetic operations you need. Go ahead and do a subtraction is that satisfies the requirements.

Comment: , i.quantity - IFNULL(t.quantity,0) + IFNULL(r.quantity,0) AS calc_qty

Comment: , i.quantity - IFNULL(t.quantity,0) + IFNULL(r.quantity,0) AS calc_qty should be
, i.quantity - IFNULL(t.quantity,0) - IFNULL(r.quantity,0) AS calc_qty

Comment: It just seemed really strange to me to subtract the returned quantity... it's not at all clear to me what the value of `calc_quantity` is supposed to represent... so I just threw in a different operator, replacing a subtraction with addition. I considered leaving the calc_quantity expression out entirely, but I wanted to demonstrate a reference to that in HAVING clause. (didn't seem like the calculation was what the question was about... fundamental issue is pre-aggregating quantity from the two tables child, and using outer joins, and handling NULL values,

Comment: Your solution is perfect! Thanks spencer!